# How to make 'send' as non-blocking in winsock

Tags: c++, windows, networking

I am making a program which sends UDP packet to server at a fixed interval, something like this:

```
while (!stop) {
    Sleep(fixedInterval);

    send(sock, pkt, payloadSize, flags);
 }
```

However the periodicity cannot be guaranteed for send is a blocking call (e.g., when fixedInterval is 20ms, and a call to send is > 20ms ), do you know how I can turn the send to a nonblocking operation?